# On Windows, how do we convert a virtual key code to the shifted character?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I looked at MapVirtualKey() and ToAscii().

MapVirtualKey() gives me only the unshifted character. ToAscii() only works for vk codes that translate to ASCII values.

I need to detect for example, "Ctrl + Shift + 3" as Ctrl active, Shift active and '#'.

Any clues?

Comment: I don't get it, why don't you just use WM_CHAR?  GetKeyState() to get the state of the Ctrl and Shift keys.

Comment: You cannot use WM_CHAR because Ctrl+3 does not get mapped to '#'. In fact I kept getting character code 1 for many Ctrl-key combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I finally did it:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
        GetKeyboardState(kbs);
        if(kbs[VK_CONTROL] & 0x00000080)
        {
            kbs[VK_CONTROL] &= 0x0000007f;
            ::ToAscii(p_wParam, ::MapVirtualKey(p_wParam, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), kbs, ch, 0);
            kbs[VK_CONTROL] |= 0x00000080;
        }
        else
            ::ToAscii(p_wParam, ::MapVirtualKey(p_wParam, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), kbs, ch, 0);
```

Then I get the states of all the modifier keys from kbs[].

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GetKeyState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to determine key state of by providing virtual key code. See also: [GetKeyboardState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646299%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).